# nscurl --ats-diagnostics doesn't work with my nodejs server

Tags: ios, iphone, node.js, ssl

I have setup nodejs for SSL with certificates from ssls.com.  When I run tests from the browser my certificates are found and things seem okay (excepting a couple of vulnerabilities are shown). I'm using sites like:
https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Notwithstanding I'm having trouble getting my IOS app to connect using a websockets library.
When I run this new diagnostic command:
nscurl --ats-diagnostics `https://<mydomain.com>` I get

> nscurl[4714:325661] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
>   nscurl[4714:325661] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)

The more detailed log file doesn't seem to give much more info:

> Error: Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
>   _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the vulnerabilities that are shown on the other sites?  Which ATS test(s) is/are failing?

Comment: All of them, and it runs extremely slow (i.e) it times out for each test I think.  However, the website tests run fine and say e.g. that TSL 1.2 passes.

Comment: For example, ssllabs.com reports that IOS7.1 shows TLS 1.2 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA NoFS and gives a bunch of protocol details: Secure Renegotiation: Supported: Secure Client-Initiated Renegotiation: No; Insecure Client-initiated Renegotiation: No; ...SSL/TLS compression:No...Forward Secrecy:No Weak; Session Resumption: No (Ids assigned but not accepted) .  There is a lot more fields in the report.

Comment: Right, so if you are failing things on SSLLabs then you will fail with a default ATS configuration.  You need to either correct those issues or disable/weaken ATS.  For example, the default ATS configuration requires forward secrecy

Comment: Refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/ for the default requirements

Comment: Yes I just tried in my app plist settings having NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy NO.  That worked for the app, but I thought the point of --ats-diagnostics was to try all combinations, and be useful for debugging issues???  I tried nscurl --ats-diagnostics --ats-disable-pfs https://example.com and it still hangs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91453/discussion-between-bhartsb-and-paulw11).

Comment: An aside, will Apple reject an app with disabled or weakened ATS?

Comment: No. You can do whatever you need for your app to work